# Why does Eclipse install to this directory?

Tags: apt, filesystem, eclipse

After installing Eclipse IDE via `apt-get install eclipse` I found the Eclipse folder in directory:

`/usr/share/eclipse`

But after I found directions that I must copy this folder to the directory:

`/usr/local/eclipse`.

Please, help me understand two points:

Why does Eclipse install in `/usr/share`? Why not the other directory?

And why must I move the folder to the `/usr/share` directory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you install a package, many files might be installed in many places. Checking out the contents of the `eclipse` package for Oneiric on http://packages.ubuntu.com shows me that it (indirectly) depends on the package `eclipse-platform`, and the [file list for that package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/oneiric/amd64/eclipse-platform/filelist) shows me that it installs many files under `/usr/lib/eclipse` and an executable (or link) in `/usr/bin`.

You do not need to copy any folders or files yourself after installing this package; it's not a good idea to do that, because then the package management system can't keep track of the files (if you uninstall it, the package management system won't know that you've manually moved the files around).

(Why do you think that you need to move files around manually?).

Comment: I used this link: http://www.kochnielsen.dk/kurt/blog/?p=208

Comment: @user471011: Those steps apply **only** when installing eclipse **manually**, not using `apt-get`. So you have to decide either to use `apt-get` **or** following that blog entry.